# Can a stored procedure on the master DB create a regular DB? SQL Server 2012 and later

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have all my scripts and procedures ready for this database project but I'd like to have a stored procedure that creates my database and all my tables. Potentially drop it (if it exists) in the proc as well but for now I'll just focus on creating it.

I assume it's something to do with the Master DB but can't figure it out.

Would it look something like this:

```
USE master

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.myDB' ) IS NULL

CREATE PROCEDURE myNewDatabase
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE myDB
END

ELSE
PRINT 'myDB Database already exists'
```

Note: then I would have to do another stored proc to create all the tables right? Also a bit confused as the 'if object_id is null' usually checks for procedure names but this one is checking database name?

Can someone tell me whether my thinking is on the right track at lease?

Thank you

Comment: "I'd like to have a stored procedure that actually creates my database and all my tables"  Why?  I've never heard of someone wanting to do that.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Aside from being completely strange you would have to use dynamic sql for this. I just can't even begin to wrap my head around why this would provide any benefit.

Comment: Yea well maybe I'm understanding something wrong but my professor who is a DBA for JP Morgan says if we do this we get extra credit on our project?  I would assume he knows what he's talking about but at my level I'm honestly not sure.  Trying to learn.

Comment: Haha well I guess that why I'm getting points docked.  I mean if you have a database that you're constantly playing with would it not be good to have a procedure that cleans it out and makes a new one?  I guess yes this would make no sense in the real world.

Comment: @SeanLange  I guess I need to learn dynamic sql.  Thanks

Comment: If you have a database that you are working with and you want to be able to get it back to a specific point you would either script the entire database or create a backup of the database when it is in the state you want to maintain. Then you either simply drop the database and run your script or you restore your database from the backup. A stored procedure to generate an entire database would require dynamic sql and be a huge challenge.

Comment: @SeanLange  I see, I guess I should not go for the extra credit then.  Sounds too tough to learn dynamic sql in a week to do something that does not make sense in the business world.  Thanks!

Comment: The post below from digital.aaron is reasonably close to working for the database creation. You will then need to create all your tables, data, and other objects with dynamic sql.

Comment: Got it,  thanks Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying it's a good idea to create databases this way (because it isn't), but if you really want to, here's how:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.myNewDatabase
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(100) = 'myDB'
        ,@path VARCHAR(1000) = 'C:\Test\'
        ,@sql VARCHAR(1000);



IF DB_ID(@dbname) IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @sql =
        'CREATE DATABASE ' + @dbname + ' ON (NAME = ' + @dbname
        + '_Data, FILENAME = ''' + @path + @dbname + '.mdf'')'
        + ' LOG ON (NAME = ' + @dbname + '_Log, FILENAME = ''' + @path + @dbname
        + '.ldf'')';
    EXEC(@sql);
END
ELSE
PRINT 'myDB Database already exists'

GO
```

Comment: You can ignore StackOverflow's incorrect syntax highlighting here.

Comment: Great thanks.  I appreciate the help.   It sounded strange to me too.  Now I know I'm not the only one.

Comment: You could simplify this if you wanted and skip the file names and path. Simply the create database with a name will work. It will by default create the data and log files with the same name as the database and put them in the default folders. And make the dbname a parameter and this would pretty much do it.

Comment: It is very odd to put it in a stored procedure. However, it is beneficial to have scripts that can build your database. If you are writing an install package one of the steps might be creating a localized database, you'd have to call the script to generate the database, but the benefit of putting it in a stored proc is unlikely the right way to do this.